# How to crop an image using data from jQuery Guillotine Plugin with Imagick

Tags: php, image, crop, imagick

I've searched everywhere for two days now, still no help.

my project uses [jQuery Guillotine Plugin](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) to allow users select image size and position before uploading to my php server but i can't figure out the proper way to crop and scale the image based on the data received from the frontend.

Here is what i've tried:

The response i'm trying to work with looks like this:

```
{ scale: 0.324, angle: 0, x: 110, y: 34, w: 300, h: 300 }
```

Then the php code:

```
$imagick = Image::make($destination . "/" . $fileName);
$height = $imagick->height();
$width = $imagick->width();

$imagick->rotate($req['angle']);
//using the data recieved after user selection
$imagick->cropImage((int)$req['w'], (int)$req['h'], (int)$req['x'], (int)$req['y']);
//Write image to disk
$imagick->save($destinationPathSmaller . $fileName);
```

At this point, the picture doesn't display correctly. i really don't know what to do, this is my 3rd day on this. please help!

Thanks in inadvance,

Comment: At what part in the process are you experiencing a breakdown?
1. They pick an image. 2.) They change the settings on it. 3.) They post the image with the settings. 4.) You save the file.

Comment: It's point 4.) when i want to save the file, i don't know how to crop the data to look exactly the way the user has selected it.

Comment: What are the values that you're getting back in the `$req` array?

Comment: Also, I'm just curious. Is this `Image` class a derivitive of the `Imagick`  class in PHP? and does it's `crop` method work the same as `cropImage`?

Comment: yes, the `crop` method is from php intervention which uses `Imagick` as it's driver. the value i get from the frontend looks like: ` { scale: 1.4, angle: 270, x: 10, y: 20, w: 900, h: 675 } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so i finally got it working.

I thank everyone that tried to help, here is what i did in case someone else is faced with same issue:

Using [Intervention](http://image.intervention.io) and *Imagick* as the driver.

After collecting your data from the [guillotine](https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine) API, process it and use it like this.

```
$imagick = Image::make($destination . "/" . $fileName);
$width = $imagick->width() * $req['scale'];

$imagick->rotate($req['angle']);
$imagick->widen($width);

//Crop to desired width and height. 
//Note: the width and height has to be same with what you set on your Guillotine config when instantiating it. 
$imagick->crop($req['w'], $req['h'], $req['x'], $req['y']);

//Finally, Save your file
$imagick->save($new_destination . $fileName);
```

That should just work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's just a different in copying and pasting but I think this may be a simple misusage of the library.

For one. You have this line:

```
$imagick = new Image($destination . "/" . $fileName);
```

But they suggest that you use

```
$imagick = Image::make($destination . "/" . $fileName);
```

The difference between the two is that a driver is not getting set if you simply call `new Image`. So the crop method simply bounces off the AbstractDriver class they have and does nothing. But you can call `Image::make` and it will [return the driver](https://github.com/Intervention/image/blob/44c9a6bb292e50cf8a1e4b5030c7954c2709c089/src/Intervention/Image/ImageManager.php#L50).

If that doesn't seem to be the case then I also noticed that you're using `writeImage`. PHP Interventions method for creating a file based on changes is [`->save();`](http://image.intervention.io/api/save). I couldn't find the method `writeImage` anywhere.

Comment: that was a mistake in the question, what i'm using is: `$imagick = Image::make($destination . "/" . $fileName);`  but at the moment i'm not having any php error, just that my image is not resizing the way i want.   I use  `writeImage`  to save the image using when using [Imagick](http://phpimagick.com/Imagick) (not in the doc but works).

Comment: I don't know. The only other thing I can think of is that image magic isn't configured correctly. But then the rotate wouldn't be working either.